# Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java

I am getting the following error following error in my server log, I do not know which method is throwing this error and what is the cause of this error. Can any one help me?

```
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[default]]
(http--103.8.126.145-80-7) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:408)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:852)
    [struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar:2.3.4.1]  at
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:534)
    [struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar:2.3.4.1]  at
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
    [struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar:2.3.4.1]  at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```